# Overriding 'clean' lifecycle in Maven

Tags: maven-2, build, maven, build-process

I was going through a book that explain how to override 'default' lifecycle of Maven.

It says: To define a new lifecycle for a packaging type, you'll need to configure a LifecycleMapping component in Plexus. In your plugin project, create a META-INF/plexus/components.xml under src/main/resources. In components.xml add the content as shown below, and you're done. With below configuration, I'm able to customize the default lifecycle for 'jar' packaging type. Now If I exeute 
$ mvn package

 
It straigh away executes 'package' phase skipping all other phases of default lifecycle and executes 'echo' goal of 'maven-zip-plugin'.

```
<component-set>
    <components>
        <component>
            <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
            <role-hint>zip</role-hint>
            <implementation>
                org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
            </implementation>
            <configuration>
                <phases>
                    <package>org.sonatype.mavenbook.plugins:maven-zip-plugin:echo
                    </package>
                </phases>
            </configuration>
        </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```

My question is: How can I customize 'clean' lifecycle. For example, assume when some one types 
$ mvn clean

Instead of running clean:clean that will execute 'clean' goal of 'maven-clean-plugin' plugin, I wanted to execute 'customClean' goal of 'customPlugin'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For what you describe, it is simpler to just prevent the `maven-clean-plugin` from running during the `clean` phase, and attach customPlugin to the `clean` phase instead.  This is simpler than short-circuiting the whole lifecycle, and keeps all your maven config in your pom.

## 1 prevent the maven-clean-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## 2 attach your own plugin to the clean phase

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-customPlugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>customPlugin-version</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>customised-clean</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>customClean</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>clean</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That is a much more elegant solution

Comment: Yes.. this is simplest solution for my problem.

Comment: <skip>true</skip> is not working for me. i have disabled the resources:resources goal by <phase/> i.e. emptying the phase binding.